# How do I ignore test failures without ignoring other kinds of task failures with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, continue

So I've noticed that the CLI option `--continue` is often used to handle test failures but it's not specific to them. Is there a means by which I can handle ONLY test failures and not other types of Task failures? If another non-test task fails that would seem to be something worth halting the build over even if tests are not in that specific instance. Also, my integration tests seem to be ignoring it. My setup is the one specified here, in this HOWTO:

http://bit.ly/1S5PKlr

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:ignoreFailures

Comment: ...and you set that from the command line?

Comment: You can just use a property, test if it's present, and set this property if it is: `if (project.hasProperty('ignoreFailures')) { ignoreFailures = true }`. Then use `-PignoreFailures`.

Comment: Ouch. I've got to set that pragmatically for each of these tasks on a project of this size? This could be an issue. :-/

Comment: Maybe there is another solution, but that one is simple and should work. What do you mean by "a project of this size"? You can configure all test tasks of all projects that way by simply looping over all the projects and test tasks. Shouldn't be more than a few lines of code.

Comment: I'm new to Gradle and groovy as well. Seems like a pretty big perf hit if I have to do that iteration every time or a pretty big code hit if I have to write it in every task. Think we have somewhere in the neighborhood of 100+ sub projects. ...nope just counted em. Only 96. Suppose I could shell script something that mods the build.gradle files.

Comment: I'm not saying you should do that with a shell script. Do that from the build of the root project itself, using gradle. `allprojects { // configure each project here }`. If you have such a huge project driven by Gradle, you should invest time in learning gradle and how you can configure many/all projects at once. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Comment: Yeah, a re-read of that probably wouldn't hurt. Been lost in the sub-projects for quite some time.